# Redirect message from awk condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I would like to redirect my custom message when checking connectivity from my server to a log file. I am breaking from the condition using exit 1, but how to make it more verbose and redirect to a log file?

How can I accomplish that within `awk` itself to fit nicely the message with the redirect:

```
awk { ... "Connectivity to ${rda} failed, exiting" >> ${log} ... } then
```

My script is as follows:

```
#/bin/bash
rda="www.google.com"                       
log="/var/log/connectivity.log"

if nc -zw1 ${rda} 22 && echo |openssl s_client -connect ${rda}:22 2>&1 |awk '
    handshake && $1 == "Verification" { if ($2=="OK") exit;exit 1; }
    $1 $2 == "SSLhandshake" { handshake = 1 }'
then
    echo -e "Connectivity works" >> ${log}
    exit 0
fi
```

My awk version is:

```
# awk -W version mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits: max NF             32767 sprintf buffer      2040
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has already been described you can use this construct to write (and continue writing) to a file:

```
awk '{ print "hello, world" >>"file.log" }'
```

The other part of the puzzle is how to get your shell variable `$log` into `awk` without complex quoting. The `-v` flag allows you to define an `awk` variable, which in this case we set to be the value of the shell variable `$log`:

```
awk -v logfile="$log" { print "Appending to", logfile, "here" >>logfile }'
```

(I didn't use `log="$log"` because `awk` variants (at least `mawk` and `gawk`) use `log` as a built-in and won't allow it to be redefined.)

Answer (score 1):

You can `print` to a file in `awk` using

```
print "data" >"somefile.log"
```

or

```
filename="somefile.log"
print "data" >filename
```

Using `>` will truncate the file on the first `print`, but the file will remain open until the script ends or you explicitly `close()` the file.  While the file is open (after the first `print >`), subsequent calls to `print >` would add to the file without truncating.

To append to an existing file, use `print >>`.

Example using a log filename from the command line:

```
... | awk -v out="$log" { print "this is a message" >>out }
```

or,

```
... | out=$log awk { print "this is a message" >>ENVIRON["out"] }
```

The above would append to the (possibly) preexisting file with the pathname in the shell variable `log`.  The second example uses the *environment variable* `out` as the file path to write to (this is set to `$log` on the command line for `awk`).

Answer (score 0):

You could combine all the logging into one `awk` script. Try adapting your script like

```
awk -v rda="${rda}"'

handshake &&
$1 == "Verification"    {if ($2=="OK")  {print "Connectivity works"
                                         exit
                                        }
                         print "Connectivity to " rda " failed, exiting"
                         exit 1
                        }

$1 $2 == "SSLhandshake" {handshake = 1
                        }
' >> "${log}"
```

If you want to differentiate between normal and error output, redirect errors to `/dev/stderr` within `awk`.